# How to save data from a .txt file as an array

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program which reads in a a list of nodes that interact with each other within a network. This is written in a text file in the format:

```
node1   node2
node1   node3
node2   node3
node3   node5
node2   node1
```

The program will be able to read in this file and will remove any repeated interactions and will be able to return to me the number of interactions a node has with other nodes if I input the name of the node. I am a complete beginner at Java and although I have managed to get it to read in the file (seen below) I do not know how to save this data as an array so that I can call individual nodes, say node1, and return an integer value of how many nodes it is connected to and what these nodes are:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        File my_file = new File("(Pathway to file)/nodes.txt");
        Scanner my_scanner = new Scanner(my_file);
        
        while(my_scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(my_scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

This will output the data I want but not save it as an array.
Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest changing your file format to:

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
3 5
2 1
```

Since the rest adds no information. If you have no control over the file format there are other workarrounds (you could look into using RegEx).

You can use a ArrayList of Sets to repressent your connections, that way there will be no duplicate connections. If you really need an array you can convert it later using the `toArray()` method of ArrayList.

The code bellow should do every thing you describe and print every node followed by all the nodes it is connected to, if you change the format of the text file as suggested:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DavidSmith {
    private static ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> connections;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner my_scanner = new Scanner(DavidSmith.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("(Pathway to file)/nodes.txt"));
        connections = new ArrayList<>();
        while(my_scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int node1 = my_scanner.nextInt(), node2 = my_scanner.nextInt();
            while (connections.size() <= Math.max(node1, node2)) connections.add(null);
            if (connections.get(node1) == null) {
                HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
                set.add(node2);
                connections.set(node1,set);
            } else {
                connections.get(node1).add(node2);
            }
            if (connections.get(node2) == null) {
                HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
                set.add(node1);
                connections.set(node2,set);
            } else {
                connections.get(node2).add(node1);
            }
        }
        printConnections();
    }
    public static void printConnections(int node) {
        for (int node = 0; node<connections.size(); node++) {
            if (connections.get(node) == null) continue;
            System.out.print("node" + node + " is connected to: ");
            for (int connection : connections.get(node)) System.out.print("node" + connection + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
node1 is connected to: node2 node3 
node2 is connected to: node1 node3 
node3 is connected to: node1 node2 node5 
node5 is connected to: node3
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your nodes to a list, and convert that to an array, e.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    File my_file = new File("(Pathway to file)/nodes.txt");
    Scanner my_scanner = new Scanner(my_file);
    String[] myArray;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while(my_scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = my_scanner.nextLine();
        for (String word : line.split(" +")) {
          list.add(word);
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    myArray = list.toArray();
}
```